# Windows Mobile 6.1 Automated Application Web Deployment

Tags: mobile, deployment, windows-mobile-6, automated-deploy

I am working on deploying an application to a mass of windows mobile 6.1 devices and I need to come up with an automated-as-possible solution.

I need to do the following tasks:
1. Install an application CAB file to the devices (contains within it a CF 3.5 CAB if needed)
2. Run the installation on the devices
3. Change some device settings (background, theme, Items on the "Today" screen, etc)

How much of this can I automate in a script? And what's the best way to deploy it? I would ideally like to get this accomplished over some form of web delivery.